# How to use react-native to open a bootstrap modal WebView

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, react-native

I have used react-native to open a WebView from a ruby on rails app. The page includes an unopened bootstrap modal.  How do I open the modal using a react-native call, so the modal can be displayed without reloading the page?

The modal can be activated by javascript that runs in WebView page e.g.

```
    $("#myModal").modal('show');
```

The modal might look like this

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Confirmation</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>Do you want to save changes you made to document before closing?</p>
                <p class="text-warning"><small>If you don't save, your changes will be lost.</small></p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please upload some code for us to take a look at. What have you tried?

Comment: I have added an example of the code in the WebView above. I am not sure how to proceed in react-native, basically I want to inject and run javascript like ```$("#myModal").modal('show');``` without reloading the WebView page.